# how to set press style in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

It's OK when I set Selected Style.
But when I try:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "press");
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "Press");
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "PRESS");
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "pressed");
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "Pressed");
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle(uiid, style, "PRESSED");
```

nothing happens. Please someone tell me why and how to set style to pressed component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty advanced feature that you should probably avoid, you would be much better off defining several themes and proceeding from that point. Also when working with an individual component this would work better.

This will have no effect on the currently showing form/component but if you really insist the correct spelling is "press".

Comment: Thank you @Shai! I've used setThemeProps instead and it is looking good. But I need to rewrite all. Can you show me how to set pressed style for a component from code. I need it for some component.

Comment: cmp.getPressedStyle().setFgColor(...) etc. This will be applied instantly.